# Pass dataset with ksoap2 from android to webservice

Tags: c#, android, web-services, dataset, ksoap2

I have some method in c# web-service like:

```
public String TestDs(DataSet fDS);
```

My problem is that I cannot change web service.
While I trying i wrote method that making Dataset from xml And that work fine.

```
public string TestDs1(String fDSString)
{
     DataSet fDS=new DataSet();        
     fDS.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(fDSString)));
     ....
}
```

This work fine,but like I say I cannot changing web-service.
Is there any possible way to I send some string,XML, or something like that. To web-service.And that webservice understand this parameter like DataSet.
I trying to do from `android` application with `ksoap2`.

I not find way to make dataset in android,and every way on witch i try send xml for dataset web-service not understand.

On the end simply i have

```
   public String TestDs(DataSet fDS); //webservice
```

i need call this from android and pass it DataSet.
Is this even possible?
Thanx